# How can I pass a generic parameter <T> to an ASP.NET Core Tag Helper?

Tags: asp.net-core, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I've been migrating some custom MVC HTML Helpers to [ASP.NET Core Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Most of have migrated fine, but I'm stuck on one that requires a generic parameter. This helper is used to generate (Bootstrap style) pagination HTML and passes in a custom generic class called `Paging<T>` where `T` is the type that is being paginated (so to paginate a list of strings you'd have `Paging<string>` or to paginate a list of customers you'd have `Paging<Customer>` etc).

The signature of the existing HTML Helper looks similar to this:

`static IHtmlContent? Pagination<T>(this HtmlHelper helper, Paging<T> paging)`

If I try and create a similar Tag Helper with a `Paging<T>` parameter then it looks like this:

```
public class PaginationTagHelper<T> : TagHelper
{
    public Paging<T> Paging { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        /// main code coes here
    }
}
```

This compiles but it is never invoked, presumably because you can't have a generic Tag Helper class. The framework doesn't pick it up.

I could make a concrete version of the Paging class using inheritance and use that e.g.

```
public class PagedCustomer : Paging<Customer>
{
}
```

However, this defeats the point of having a generic pagination method that can page any object. I'd end up having to write one for every class.

I've thought about somehow just passing in an `Object` but then how do I cast it to the type `<T>` so it can be used? I've also looked at the [ModelExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.modelexpression?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class as a parameter, but unsure how that could be used?

So what are my options? Is there a way I can get around this?

Comment: Why you need to pass the type for pagination? Does [this taghelper](https://docs.ziyad.info/en/LazZiya.TagHelpers/v6.0/index.md) help?

Comment: @LazZiya The `Paging<T>` class contains all the information about what is being paged, including the list of items. I'll look at your example, though, and see if it helps. Thanks. But would be nice to know if there is a way of using generics with Tag Helpers.

Comment: instead of using generic type taghelper, maybe you can define a new parameter for the type inside the taghelper.

Comment: @LazZiya Yeah, I've gone the road of having an interface that is a sub-set of the Paging class and using that, as (like you say) I don't really need the type to generate pagination from. So thanks for that hint. But I'm still curious how you would write a generic tag helper...